# Is there a way to run an angular 2 application under another application in a decoupled way?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, frontend, angular2-routing

Here is the situation: 
I have an angular 2 application developed by one team and I want to develop another angular 2 application seperated from them BUT I need that in their application, when you click on a link it will load my application but with all their layout (header, menu, side menu, etc.).

I am using webpack and angular 2

Is there a way to do so without them having to npm install my application when the deploy?

Is there a way for them to consume my application after it was built and bundled seperately?

Thanks!